# Unexpected result of C Ternary Operator

Tags: vector, conditional-operator

I found a strange behavior of C ternary operator (?:).
In the following code, the expected values of both b and c should be 0, but b is -2.
I checked the [C operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), and made sure minus(-) is higher than greater than or equal to (>=), which is higher than the conditional operator (?:). Could anyone kindly explain why the values of b and c are different?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
        int i;
        vector<int> a;
        for (i = 0; i < 29; ++i)
                a.push_back(i);
        int b = 27 - a.size() >= 0 ? 27 - a.size() : 0;
        int c = 27 - 29 >=0 ? 27 - 29 : 0;
        cout << b << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking on the document page of [vector](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), the return type of method size() is size_t which is equal to an unsigned long long.

So, when you do `27 - a.size()` this will cause overflow, making the result of the `27 - a.size() >= 0` operator be `True`. It got nothing to do with C operator precedence.

To prove that, you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
        unsigned long long tmp = 29;
        cout << 27 - tmp << endl; //(this will be a super large integer.)
        return 0;
}
```

### Solution:

The solution is simple, you can simply add a typecasting `(int)` before `a.size()` in the condition of the ternary operator.
It can be looks like this:

`int b = 27 - (int) a.size() >= 0 ? 27 - a.size() : 0;`

Comment: You have diagnosed the problem in the OP's code, and even added your own code to demonstrate that problem. However, what you *haven't* done is provide a solution.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for reminding me to add a solution. I also change the code for the overflow demonstration to make it more clean.